# Eclipse see library but cannot import it

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, testing

I have strange situation:

I write class:

```
...
    import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
    //import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

    @WebAppConfiguration
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
    public class CandidateControllerTest {
...
```

If I type ctrl+mouse left button and move cursor on WebAppConfiguration I see:

[image]

But in my redactor I see:

[image]

if I move cursor for anotation I saw message:

> WebAppConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type

How ti fix it this problem?

**RESOLVE**

my application has 2 modules. dependendency for spring test(test scope) was writing in core module. when I wrote dependency in second module - it had become to work.

Comment: My guess, conflicting classpath entries for spring-test.

Answer (score 1):

Add proper dependency to the project class path or if you use maven, probably wrong spring version is resolved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does - proper dependency is missing for the project, User need to add jar or library (plug-in?) dependency to his/her project.

Comment: @agad I'm also having the same problem and I'm sure I have the POM configure properly. But I wasn't sure which dependencies is needed in my project.